# Using generic getters and setters with php

Tags: php, getter-setter

There's thousands of examples of php __get and __set out there, unfortunately nobody actually tells you how to use them.

So my question is: how do I actually call the __get and __set method from within the class and when using an object.

Example code:

```
class User{
public $id, $usename, $password;

public function __construct($id, $username) {
         //SET AND GET USERNAME
}

public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
        return $this->$property;
    }
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}
}

$user = new User(1, 'Bastest');
// echo GET THE VALUE;
```

How would I set the values in the constructor and how would i get the value in the `// echo GET THE VALUE;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you've read, but suggest you to read [official manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) - since obviously you're not understanding for which purposes `__set()` and `__get()` are needed.

Comment: in your setter, $this->$property = $value; needs to be $this->$property = $value[0];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is called `overloading` in PHP. As the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) states the `__get` or `__set` methods will be called if you are trying to access non existent or non accessible properties. The problem in your code is, that the properties your are accessing are existent and accessible. That's why `__get`/`__set` will not being called.

Check this example:

```
class Test {

    protected $foo;

    public $data;

    public function __get($property) {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
$a = new Test();

// property 'name' does not exists
$a->name = 'test'; // will trigger __set
$n = $a->name; // will trigger __get

// property 'foo' is protected - meaning not accessible
$a->foo = 'bar'; // will trigger __set
$a = $a->foo; // will trigger __get

// property 'data' is public
$a->data = '123'; // will not trigger __set
$d = $a->data; // will not trigger __get
```

Comment: Thanks I figured this was it and tried it as well. Problem was of course that the public variables in my example should be private include that in your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @inControl You can also explicitly call `$this->__set()` or this `$this->__get()`. This is interesting if you are accessing protected properties from inside a class